# Twilio - Can I use a webhook, TwiML, Studio or Function to route Voice Calls to an elastic sip trunk

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I want to setup Failover routing within Twilio phone numbers. If I can use a Webhook or other Twilio method that offers "Primary Handler Fails" then I can do this within specific numbers. I know how to create method for forwarding call to a different number that I can place in that failover field. Here is what I don't know:

How do I direct the first field "A Call Comes In" to my Elastic Sip Trunk?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't setup calls to be forwarded to your SIP trunk in general, however you can have them forwarded to a SIP address that is registered on your trunk.

To do so, you need to use the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb, nesting a [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sip) inside. Like this:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>SIP_ADDRESS</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```